# Contar cantidad de repeticiones por parejas usando pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[Una pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/163569/como-convertir-una-lista-de-2-columnas-en-una-matriz) reciente, que no especificaba con qué lenguaje/tecnología quería resolverlo, me impulsó a pensar cómo lo haría con Pandas.

La pregunta puede reformularse en el contexto de Pandas en la forma siguiente.

Dado un dataframe como por ejemplo el que construyo aquí:

```
import pandas as pd
datos = [["jose", "manzana"],
         ["andres","pera"],
         ["luis", "pera"],
         ["jose", "manzana"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns=["Nombre", "Fruta"])
print(df)
```

Que tiene esta pinta:

```
   Nombre    Fruta
0    jose  manzana
1  andres     pera
2    luis     pera
3    jose  manzana
```

quiero obtener otro en el que el índice sean los nombres (sin repeticiones), las columnas las frutas, y las celdas el número de veces que cada nombre aparece con cada fruta. Es decir:

```
Fruta   manzana  pera
Nombre               
andres        0     1
jose          2     0
luis          0     1
```

### Mi intento

Parece que esto está pidiendo una `pivot_table()`, pero para poder resolverlo no se me ha ocurrido otra forma que añadir al dataframe original una columna extra llena de `1`:

```
>>> print(df.assign(Cuantas=1))
   Nombre    Fruta  Cuantas
0    jose  manzana        1
1  andres     pera        1
2    luis     pera        1
3    jose  manzana        1
```

Para poder usar esa columna como valor a sumar en la `pivot_table`. Mi solución queda por tanto así:

```
sol = df.assign(Cuantas=1).pivot_table(
        index="Nombre", 
        columns="Fruta", 
        values="Cuantas", 
        aggfunc="sum", 
        fill_value=0)
```

y efectivamente esto da el resultado buscado, pero me parece un poco farragoso.

La pregunta es **¿Hay otra forma más sencilla?**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas parece ser lo que se llama [tabla de contingencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabla_de_contingencia), `pandas` tiene esa funcionalidad en [`crosstab()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html#pandas-crosstab), puedes hacer algo así:

```
import pandas as pd

datos = [["jose", "manzana"],
         ["andres","pera"],
         ["luis", "pera"],
         ["jose", "manzana"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(datos, columns=["Nombre", "Fruta"])

print(pd.crosstab(df.Nombre, df.Fruta))
```

Salida:

```
Fruta   manzana  pera
Nombre               
andres        0     1
jose          2     0
luis          0     1
```

Comment: Sabía que tenía que haber una forma directa :-) Gracias!